# WPF, linking together two XML data sources in cascading ComboBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, datatemplate

I have XML in the following format:

```
<Products>
  <Product name="MyProduct1">
    <Components>
      <Component name="MyComponent1">
        <Teams>
          <Team id="1"/>
          <Team id="4"/>
        </Teams>
      </Component>
    </Components>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

This is stored in an external XML file that is included via an `XmlDataProvider` in my XAML:

```
<XmlDataProvider Source="Products.xml"
                 XPath="Products/Product"
                 x:Key="productsXml"/>
```

You'll see that the `Team` nodes have only an `id` attribute; this links them to other XML that is embedded directly in my XAML:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="teamsXml" XPath="Teams/Team">
    <x:XData>
        <Teams xmlns="">
            <Team name="Team A" id="1"/>
            <Team name="Team B" id="2"/>
            <Team name="Team C" id="3"/>
            <Team name="Team D" id="4"/>
        </Teams>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

I have the following ComboBox in my XAML:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="133,217,0,0"
          Name="cbo_team" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148"
          DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbo_component, Path=SelectedItem}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Teams/Team}"
          SelectedIndex="0" />
```

This ComboBox shows a list of Teams associated with the currently selected Component.  I need to keep `DataContext` and `ItemsSource` the same here so that only the related Teams are shown, and not all available Teams.  However, I don't want to show the Team `id` attribute in the ComboBox, I want to show the `name` attribute as it is defined in `teamsXml`, e.g., Team A.  How can I use a `DataTemplate` and somehow get the Team name from `teamsXml` when I have the Team `id` from `productsXml`?  I also want the value of the ComboBox to be the `name` attribute.

**Edit:**

I'm wondering if something like this is a step in the right direction:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="133,217,0,0"
            Name="cbo_team" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148"
            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbo_component, Path=SelectedItem}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Teams/Team}"
            SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource teamsXml}"
                 XPath="???"/> <!-- Need to select the @name attribute of the node
                                    whose @id attribute is the same value as the
                                    current selected item in this ComboBox -->
    </ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, [this guy's article](http://karlhulme.wordpress.com/2007/02/14/xpath-variabledynamic-parameters-in-wpf-binding/#comment-2446) helped me out.  I moved my `Teams` XML into my Products.xml file, so I have the following format:

```
<Products>
  <Product name="MyProduct1">
    <Components>
      <Component name="MyComponent1">
        <Teams>
          <Team id="1"/>
          <Team id="4"/>
        </Teams>
      </Component>
    </Components>
  </Product>
  <Teams>
    <Team name="Team A" id="1"/>
    <Team name="Team B" id="2"/>
    <Team name="Team C" id="3"/>
    <Team name="Team D" id="4"/>
  </Teams>  
</Products>
```

Then, I did the following for my ComboBox in XAML:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="133,218,0,0"
          Name="cbo_team" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148"
          DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbo_component, Path=SelectedItem}">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding XPath="Teams/Team/@id"
                 Converter="{StaticResource xmlConverter}">
            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                <local:XmlConverterParameter
                    XPathTemplate="/Products/Teams/Team[{0}]"
                    XPathCondition="@id='{0}'" />
            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I had to include the following in my `<Window.Resources>` in XAML:

```
<local:XmlConverter x:Key="xmlConverter"/>
```

And, following his tutorial, I created two C# classes:  `XmlConverter` and `XmlConverterParameter`.  Now my ComboBox converts a team `id` to a `name` and displays the `name`, so my XML is fairly DRY because the team names are only defined in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Linq to xml and fill a CollectionViewSource. Then bind to that rather than xmlDataProvider.

Comment: Okay.  It seems like I could write a C# method that, given `id`s, would return `name`s, using LINQ to XML.  How would I call this method and give it `id`s from XAML, though?

Comment: Looks like this might be useful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663356/how-can-i-call-a-bound-method-in-xaml-with-the-parameter-of-a-tabitems-name