# WPF Expression blend calling a method on data source programmatically

Tags: wpf, datasource, expression-blend

I am a bit puzzle by this problem.

I have created a library assembly with visual studio 2010 that exposes several things, like observable collections and methods to report some data.

Then I created a WPF project in Expression Blend 4 that has a reference to this assembly and I also created a datasource object from this assembly. So far so good.

When I look in the data view of Blend 4, I can see the observable collections and methods of the data source. I can successfully bind the observable collection to a datagrid or bind the method in XAML to a button.

But, in a very specific case, I need to programmatically call one of the methods of the datasource in my cs file. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind you can grab a handle to the data source:

`var _dataSource = Resources["YourObjectTypeDataSource"] as YourObjectType;`

Now in your code behind you can call methods (or set properties, etc.) on the data source instance directly:

```
_dataSource.YourMethodName();
```

That being said I'm sure there is a no code behind option available, but I would need to know more about the requirements to suggest a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663356/how-can-i-call-a-bound-method-in-xaml-with-the-parameter-of-a-tabitems-name) it refers to the only way I know without using any C# code.